# Preserving/disinfecting meat with alcohol?

Tags: bacteriology, pathology, food, alcohol, bacterial-toxins

I'm considering safer ways to handle raw meat and it occurred to me that alcohol might be useful.

I'm considering, say, sealing pieces of meat in a container with 40% alcohol or higher in fridge or possibly freezer.

My question is what effects will this have on potential bacteria/parasites in and on the surface of the meat, and what will happen over time.

Different results as per higher concentrations/volume of alcohol and various temperatures are a plus.

Comment: Since, then the solution is more concentrated than the eco , osmos will take place, resulting in dehydration of cells , ultimately cells collapse.

Comment: So it will actually dry it out in the center?